# HTML <pre> word wrapping in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, html, css, word-wrap

I've been working on a forum, and I've made everything work as it, and I tried wrapping to see if it works, basically that part of the code looks like this
before the PHP I got some HTML style:

```
<style>
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap; 
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
        white-space: -pre-wrap;
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;    
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0% 8% 0px 8%; 
    }
</style>
```

And then after a bunch of MySQL things

```
echo '<table style="height: 21px;" width="100%">';
while($forumcomrow=mysqli_fetch_array($forumcomres))
{
    echo '<tr><td>some text</td><td><pre>Some Very Long Text From Mysql </pre></td></tr></br>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I removed everything and just left the style for it and the echo for the table, when I echo just the pre tag, it wraps it at the end of the screen, but as soon as I put it in a table (size doesn't matter, even if I put the width of the table to 5px) it still goes 10 miles off the screen until it starts wrapping.

This is what happens:

[image: This is what happens]

On the picture above you can see one part of it, but the text goes off screen about 5x the length you can see on there, and only then starts wrapping

I have figured out what's giving it a problem, it will wrap the text if it has spaces ("aaaa aaa aaa aa aa") but if its one long word ("aaaaaaaaa") it won't wrap it, I don't know how to fix it, I've just figured out whats causing the problem.

Comment: Put whitespace break-all

Comment: The <pre> tag will only wrap to the width of the second cell in the table. Your table is hundred percent width. This may cause it to fill a lot of space, making the pre ineffective.

Comment: if i use the <pre> tag by itself in echo, it wraps the text at the end of the screen, if i use the pre tag in a table, even if i set the table width to 10px, it goes off screen, and doesnt wrap, or starts wraping somewhere far away from the end of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of `<br>` tag at the end, I have faced the same problem some time ago. `<br>` get applied first for every time and then table gets wrapped.

**Remove** `<br>` **at the end**

```
echo '<tr><td>some text</td><td><pre>Some Very Long Text From Mysql </pre></td></tr>';
```

and then it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: i removed the br and it didnt work, i copied your example and i pasted it with some long text (entered directly into the code) and it works, but as soon as i replace the long text with

      <pre>'.$forumcomrow["commenttext"].'</pre>

it doesnt work anymore, goes off screen

Comment: I checked it in my system and it is working fine. Just remove the styles of `<pre>` tag. You may use bootstrap for the styling for now.

Comment: I edited my post, it works perfectly fine if its a long sentence with spaces, but if its just one long word, it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Remove the styles you have written for `<pre>` and then try